# How do you call F# methods in a PCL that return a string option, from an Xamarin Android C# project?

Tags: xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

How do you create an F# PCL that can be called from a C# Xamarin Android project?

Something simple, like this in a PCL:

```
namespace FSharpPCL2

type Class1() = 
    member this.X (s: string option) = 
      s
      |> Option.map (fun t -> t + "stuff")
```

Try calling it from a C# Xamarin Android project, and you'll get a compiler error something like this:

> MainActivity.cs(26,41): error CS0012: The type
>   `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to
>   assembly `FSharp.Core, Version=3.78.3.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

But it's not clear to me how you actually manage to include the right FSharp.Core in the C# project.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the FSharp.Core [guidelines](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html) which explains the options you have in these scenarios.

In your case you can add a package reference to the [FSharp.Core nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core) in your C#-xamarin project. `FSharp.Core, Version=3.78.3.1` is `F# 3.1/Profile 78`. You can make sure that the version you want is referenced by viewing the version/path in References > FSharp.Core > Properties. If not you can edit the csproj and change the path to the appropriate version.

An alternative is to add a reference directly to FSharp.Core that ships with Visual/Xamarin Studio in either
`%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETCore\3.78.3.1\FSharp.Core.dll` or `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.1/lib/mono/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/FSharp/.NETCore/3.78.3.1/FSharp.Core.dll`

Comment: Turns out that adding the nuget to the C# project doesn't work - you just get the error I'm asking about.

Comment: And if it were possible to add the PCL version of FSharp.Core to the C# project (instead of the one that you might think would be correct), you almost certainly don't want to, since that would probably break other non-PCL F# projects you're including (what would happen if you tried to include an F# project that used printfn, for example, if your final project tried to just use the PCL FSharp.Core)

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an alternative, using FSharp.Core assemblies installed with VS/XS instead of nuget packages.

Regarding the nuget packages, did you add the correct version of the package? 3.78.3.1 means F# 3.1.

Finally yes, having many projects that reference different FSharp.Core will break things up; but in the end it can be fixed with [binding redirects](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#use-binding-redirects-for-applications) to the highest version, on the app that will actually run. FSharp.Core implementations are binary compatible.